# Friendly URL from query srings URL

Tags: php, url, search, friendly-url

What is the best way to do when I type a search on my site to get the url like `mysite.com/searach/blabla/video` instead of `mysite.com/?search=blabla&type=video`.
Please don't tell me that I have to use CodeIgniter because it doesn't help. I am sure that all I need is a small function in PHP.

This is my `search.php`:

```
<form id="searchwrapper" name="searchform">
<input type="text" class="searchbox" id="txtSearch" name="search" alt="Search Criteria" />
<input type="submit" src="../images/empty.png" class="searchbox_submit"/>

<p id="circ">
<input  type="radio" id="mp3" name="type" checked value="mp3"/>
<label class="circ-btn normal" for="mp3">mp3</label>
                        </p>
<p id="circ">
<input type="radio" id="album" name="type" <?php echo $radio2;?> value="album"/>
<label class="circ-btn normal" for="album">Album</label></p>                
</form>
```

My `.htacces` rules are set correctly; when I access my site directly using `mysite.com/searach/blabla/video`, it works fine, but this is not the issue. I need to have my link like this when I type a search on my site. Instead I get this link and is not right `mysite.com/?search=blabla&type=video`.

Comment: you can use .htaccess rules to rewrite the URLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others commented, you need mod_rewrite if you're using apache.

If you actually want to type in a search and end up at a SEF URL, as you described, you want something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=(\w+)&type=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://mysite.com\/%1\/%2? [R,L]
```

.. which would redirect requests such as

```
http://mysite.com/index.php?search=A&type=B
```

.. to

```
http://mysite.com/A/B
```

.. and JKirchartz provided the sample to use a php script for a SEF url, for example, having apache serve

```
http://mysite.com/video.php?search=A&type=B
```

.. behind the scenes when

```
http://mysite.com/A/B
```

.. is requested

Comment: gllen i arleady have .htaccess configurated The code that you gave me is for .htaccess too ? What code should i add in my page or search form to make it run like i wish to?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), and put this in your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^search/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?search=$1&type=$2 [L]
```

then use this in your php

```
$URI = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
$URIparts = explode("/", $URI);
```

That gives you an array with the parts of the url.

Also you should try to [sanitize the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php) for security.

Comment: JKirchartz i have updated my question with my search form, can you give me more details on how to make it work for my search form ?

Comment: @ColaDeu Use @gllen's `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` ... the form will always submit using the `get` method to put the `QUERY_STRING` in the URL, @gllen's method would rewrite that showing your desired results

Comment: i did it and it work how i need. but i have another issue. with the space. This function works only if search keyword contain no space. If i search BlaBla i get SEF URL but if i search Bla Bla. I get ?search=Bla+Bla&type=video. Can you tell me how to fix it in this code from gllen ? RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=(\w+)&type=(\w+)$

Comment: @ColaDeu you should be able to escape them with the [`[B]` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b), so try:  `[B,R,L]`

Comment: If i type space + or - in a search keyword it gives me a query url

Comment: @ColaDeu try adding `RewriteMap escape int:escape` to your `httpd.conf` then use `${escape:$1}` in place of `$1` and make the same change for `$2`

Comment: JKirchartz i edited httpd.conf on my apache .. added the code and changed $1 and $2 from my .htaccess but still the same issue. I will open another question about this. Thanks You helped my alot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache Mod Rewrite, though it can be frustrating for someone just learning it. Alternatively, you could move your site to a cms like drupal, wordpress, or joomla and have it automatically create an alias for you.